# Javascript custom sorting issue in array

Tags: javascript, sorting

i got some sort of an issue with my custom sorting. So, basically i have this array:

```
[ 'src/app/account/account.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/characters/characters.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/characters/detail/detail.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/panels/admin.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/panels/users.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/donate/donate.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/donate/donate.js',
  'src/app/account/settings/settings.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/settings/settings.js',
  'src/app/account/vote/vote.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/vote/vote.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/login.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/register.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/termsOfService.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/membership.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/membership.module.js',
  'src/app/news/news.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/news/news.js',
  'src/app/noctis.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/noctis.js',
  'src/app/widgets/playersOnline/playersOnline.js',
  'src/app/widgets/rankings/rankings.js',
  'src/app/widgets/serverDetails/serverDetails.js',
  'src/common/directives/feeds/feeds.js',
  'src/common/directives/panel/panel.js' ]
```

And what i would like that after the **src/app/** the very first **js** that comes after the very first folder after **src/app/** in our case: account, membership(can be more custom names) to be loaded first, like in the next example:

```
  ['src/app/membership/membership.module.js',
  'src/app/membership/membership.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/login.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/register.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/termsOfService.ctrl.js',]
```

Can you guys help me with some code for my needs? **src/app** will always be a fixed name except of the next **directory** that comes after **src/app/**.

Basically what comes after the unknown name of the directory after **src/app**, the sub directories in our case(dialogs) or can be something else like(detail, detail/character), to be loaded latest no matter what.

Basically this is the whole function:

```
function sortJSFiles(files) {
        var src = [];
        var vendor = [];
        files.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.startsWith('src')) {
                src.push(item);
            } else {
                vendor.push(item);
            }
        });

        src.sort(function(a, b) {
            var replace = ['noctis.js', 'noctis.ctrl.js', '.module.js', '.ctrl.js'];

            function replaceCB(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
                return previousValue.replace(currentValue, currentIndex);
            }
            return replace.reduce(replaceCB, a).localeCompare(replace.reduce(replaceCB, b));
        });
        return vendor.concat(src);
    }
```

What it does, is that in paramater files comes a lot of paths with js files and i'm trying to sort them after my rule. The problem is, for example taking **membership** example:

```
  ['src/app/membership/dialogs/login.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/register.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/termsOfService.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/membership.module.js',
  'src/app/membership/membership.ctrl.js']
```

It succesffully change the sort like loading *.js files that starts first with .module.js and than with .ctrl.js but there is a problem in my code that i need that any js file that comes after **src/app/somefolder** to be loaded first and any subfolders that are in that somefolder to be loaded latest no matter what.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Was that your question?

Comment: No, sorry, I forgot to add that i need that piece of code for that. Thank you nicely.

Comment: Why haven't you tried doing it? You have the requirements, it all seems pretty clear and it should be pretty simple.

Comment: Coding requests are off-topic for SO. You'll need to do some work and show us where you got stuck.

Comment: Well i tried and i couldn't succedd what i wanted to. Thats why im posting here for some help...

Comment: You *should* post what you tried with, and show what results it gave (or error).

Comment: can you add the sorted array and why the items are at other places as the usual sort order as comment?

Comment: Hi Nina. So basically what i need is that the *.js from "src/app/folder" to be loaded firstly and the *.js of the subdiretories from folder to be loaded latest no matter the alphabetical order. For example in folder membership i need the membership.module.js and membership.ctrl.js to be loaded firstly and the *.js in dialogs(subdirectory) folder to be loaded latest. And this rule to apply to any "src/app/folder" *.js files.

Comment: Because of my project structure in angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood you correctly (it would have been nice if you would have added the literal expected output for your sample data).

I *think* you want to have the folders sorted, but within the same folder, you want the files in there to be sorted *before* any of the subfolders in that same folder. And this should be true at every nested level.

To get the files sorted first in every folder, you should in fact extract the folders only, and sort those, and only when two items have exactly the same folder sequence, sort by the file name.

This you can do as follows:

```
src = src.map(function (path) {
    var i = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    return [path.substr(0, i), path.substr(i)];
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    var i = +(a[0] == b[0]);
    return  a[i].localeCompare(b[i]);
}).map(function (pair) {
    return pair[0] + pair[1];
});
```

```js
var src = [ 'src/app/account/account.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/characters/characters.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/characters/detail/detail.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/dashboard.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/panels/admin.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/dashboard/panels/users.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/donate/donate.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/donate/donate.js',
  'src/app/account/settings/settings.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/settings/settings.js',
  'src/app/account/vote/vote.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/account/vote/vote.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/login.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/register.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/dialogs/termsOfService.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/membership.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/membership/membership.module.js',
  'src/app/news/news.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/news/news.js',
  'src/app/noctis.ctrl.js',
  'src/app/noctis.js',
  'src/app/widgets/playersOnline/playersOnline.js',
  'src/app/widgets/rankings/rankings.js',
  'src/app/widgets/serverDetails/serverDetails.js',
  'src/common/directives/feeds/feeds.js',
  'src/common/directives/panel/panel.js' ];

src = src.map(function (path) {
    var i = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    return [path.substr(0, i), path.substr(i)];
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    var i = +(a[0] == b[0]);
    return  a[i].localeCompare(b[i]);
}).map(function (pair) {
    return pair[0] + pair[1];
});

console.log(src);
```

#### Explanation of the sort callback function

The sort callback function will receive argument *a* and *b*. Each of them is a pair including a path at index 0, and a filename at index 1.

The callback uses a variable *i* that is intended to get the value 0 or 1. If the paths of *a* and *b* are the same, then *i* will be 1, else it will be 0. It determines whether a comparison is needed on the paths or on the filenames.

The unitary `+` is used to convert the boolean expression `a[0] == b[0]` to a number. The conversion is: `true`=>`1`, `false`=>`0`.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. Can this function be reduced for more peformance boost?

Comment: I think this code is quite performant as it is. Do you ask this because you have bad performance with it?

Comment: Seems not so far, but hope you don't mind, i've modified the code inside the sort function to sort them after my specific order like ".module.js", ".ctrl.js" and it works as i wanted to. Anyway, many thanks for helping mine.

Comment: You're welcome ;-). Of course, you can modify the file sorting with the particularities you need (I am not so sure it will be intuitive to people consulting this list when some files are not following the alphabetical sort order). But for the performance: I think this should do quite well.

Comment: Can i ask what var i = +(a[0] == b[0]); this does exactly? I'm trying to understand your function but this is new for me...

Comment: that converts a boolean (comparison) to number with an unary `+`. the result is either `0` or `1`.

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer.